# $X$ is Binomially distributed with $n = 9$ and $p = 0.5$. $Y = (-1)^x$

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

We are given that $X \sim (9,0.5)$ and also that $Y = (-1)^x$.

I need to find the PMF, mean and variance of Y - which is trivial if I know the distribution of Y...

Comment: This is trivial indeed. $Y$ takes on only two values: -1,1. You can find the probability it takes on each by figuring out the chance that $X$ is even or odd.

Comment: Ah of course - thank you!!